# Replace variable in AWS cli to update secret manager password

Tags: shell, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am newbie in AWS world. I would like to update the secret credentials from aws cli.
Below command works perfect for me:

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id mysecret --region us-east-1 \
--secret-string '{"username":"anika","password":"mypwd"}'
```

But if I pass a variable `$serverPwd` it does not replace the variable `$serverPwd=mypwd`

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id mysecret --region us-east-1 \
--secret-string '{"username":"anika","password":"$serverPwd"}
```

Any thoughts how to pass variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with aws-cli but with the way the variable is being parsed. Try this:
`aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id mysecret --region us-east-1 --secret-string '{"username":"anika","password":"'"$serverPwd"'"}'`

This will allow the variable expansion properly.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI commands support the ability to accept all of the parameter input from a file using the --cli-input-json and --cli-input-yaml parameters. as the following:

- generate a template formatted in JSON

  aws secretsmanager update-secret --generate-cli-skeleton input > secretsmanage.json
- edit secretsmanage.json and provide values for the parameters you need and remove parameters you do not need.
- run aws secretsmanager update-secret using --cli-input-json parameter like the following:

  aws secretsmanager update-secret --cli-input-json file://secretsmanage.json